# Extremely Simplified Test Case for UnsatisfiedLinkError on java.lang.Package.getDeclaredAnnotations

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Why I am I getting this error on a [*standard* Android Level 10 API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Package.html)? I have created the simplest, shortest possible test case so I can paste the **entire** Android project below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  406): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: getDeclaredAnnotations
E/AndroidRuntime(  406):    at java.lang.Package.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  406):    at java.lang.Package.getDeclaredAnnotations(Package.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(  406):    at com.foobar.android.heartbeat.CustomAppWidgetProvider.onEnabled(CustomAppWidgetProvider.java:15)
E/AndroidRuntime(  406):    at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:73)
```

**1.** AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foobar.android.cannotate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <application>
        <receiver android:name="com.foobar.android.cannotate.CustomAppWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/custom_app_widget_provider_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**2.** src/com/foobar/android/cannotate/CustomAppWidgetProvider.java`

```
package com.foobar.android.heartbeat;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class CustomAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onEnabled (Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "about to get annotations");
        Annotation [] annotations = CustomAppWidgetProvider.class.getPackage().getDeclaredAnnotations();
        Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "annotations.length = " + annotations.length);
    }
}
```

**3.** res/xml/custom_app_widget_provider_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/custom_app_widget"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

**4.** res/layout/custom_app_widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

**5.** res/values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="empty">-</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you are seeing is happening because the native code method for `Package.getDeclaredAnnotations()` is not implemented by the runtime system on the platform you are running.

According to [this android issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16149), Davlik currently doesn't support Package annotations at all.  The exception is a symptom of that.

AFAIK, there's nothing you can do about it except avoid using Package annotations.  (And mobilize your friends and relatives to vote for the issue to be fixed!)

Comment: Thank you. Will this not happen on Android 4.x given the recent fix to return an empty array (per your link)?  Please note I do not wish to use package annotations and I am happy if Android returns an empty array. It is just the blow-up that is the problem and I wonder if Android 4.x will not blow up?

Comment: @agksmehx - I can't answer the question about Android 4.x.  But if you don't actually want to use the method, perhaps you should change the code to remove the calls ...

Comment: it's a library so it is difficult to remove the calls